# How to display custom lightning component in Highlights Panel of a record page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So when the user click on a button to display the lightning component in a new window.

[image]

I'm trying to display a lightning component as a button on the lightning record page in the highlights panel beside standard salesforce buttons. Is there any way to add custom component within highlights panel?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a component itself there. You can create an Action on the object that has a Lightning Component as its target, and then add that action to the Page Layout that your highlights panel is drawing from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom **Action** and add lightning component 
Make sure Lightning component has : lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader

Example

**`<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">`**

Comment: yes implements quickactionwithoutheader but does not work.

Comment: Try creating action not the button . What problem are you facing ?  [Refer Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_component_actions.htm&type=5)